Formatting xlsx in R: Highlight cell in column based on values with column names
I'm using R for my analysis to list a bunch of counts per year and species; years in columns and species across rows. I have a small dummy dataset below. The last column of the dataset (year_highlighted) shows the year in which the species was officially listed. I want to highlight the cell that corresponds to the column (year) mentioned in 'year_highlighted'.
I've seen several posts (like this) on conditional formatting, but those format the cells with the value itself. Other posts are over a decade old and I assume there are better ways now (like this). For me, I have the reference to column where the cell needs to be formatted. I want to do this all in R so that I don't have to highlight the cell manually in Excel.
Here's a small example dataset
species_year <- structure(list(fruit = c("apple", "apricot", "avocado"), `2022` = c(9.676, 
9.285, 9.557), `2023` = c(10.891, 
10.097, 9.359), `2024` = c(10.031, 
8.983, 11.389), year_highlight = c(2023, 
2024, 2023)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

Here's my expected output:


You can do this with openxlsx.
There is a more recent package openxlsx2 which may offer an alternative approach, but I've not yet made the move from its predecessor.
library(openxlsx)

# generate a vectors for column and row coordinates (cell references) for cells which need background colour
# nothing sophisticated about this approach due to the example data

row_vec <- seq_len(nrow(species_year)) + 1
col_vec <- species_year$year_highlight - 2020




wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "fruits")

writeData(wb, sheet = 1, x = species_year)

# create style for background colour
s1 <- createStyle(fgFill = "gold")

addStyle(wb, 
         sheet = 1,
         style = s1, 
         rows =  row_vec, 
         cols = col_vec)


saveWorkbook(wb, "species_year.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)

Which results in:

Created on 2024-04-18 with reprex v2.0.2

Below a conditional formatting answer:
species_year <- structure(
  list(fruit = c("apple", "apricot", "avocado"),
       `2022` = c(9.676, 9.285, 9.557), 
       `2023` = c(10.891, 10.097, 9.359), 
       `2024` = c(10.031, 8.983, 11.389), 
       year_highlight = c(2023, 2024, 2023)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -3L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

library(openxlsx2)


options("openxlsx2.string_nums" = 2) # write column names as numeric

# create workbook with data
wb <- wb_workbook()$
  add_worksheet()$
  add_data(x = species_year)

options("openxlsx2.string_nums" = NULL)

# add style for conditional formatting
wb$add_dxfs_style(
  name       = "posStyle",
  font_color = wb_color("brown"),
  bg_fill    = wb_color("gold")
)

# add conditional formatting
wb$add_conditional_formatting(
  dims  = "B1:D4",
  rule  = "B$1 = $E1",
  style = "posStyle"
)

# open the workbook
if (interactive()) wb$open()



Perhaps a question better suited for github, but I see the pull request for the more_flexible_dims branch. Do you plan to update wb_dims() to generate non-contiguous ranges?

I hope that we will be able to make wb_dims() more flexible too. Like selecting multiple columns. But no ETA on either

Another option from {openxlsx2}, but this only works from a development branch at the moment and so may be a less desirable solution.
Install DEV Version
remotes::install_github("JanMarvin/openxlsx2@more_flexible_dims")

Solution
library(openxlsx2)
library(purrr)

species_year <- structure(
  list(
    fruit = c("apple", "apricot", "avocado"), 
    `2022` = c(9.676, 9.285, 9.557), 
    `2023` = c(10.891, 10.097, 9.359), 
    `2024` = c(10.031, 8.983, 11.389), 
    year_highlight = c(2023, 2024, 2023)
  ), 
  row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

# from Peter
row_vec <- seq_len(nrow(species_year)) + 1
col_vec <- species_year$year_highlight - 2020

dims_to_fill <- purrr::map2_chr(
  row_vec, col_vec, ~ openxlsx2::wb_dims(rows = .x, cols = .y)
) %>% 
  paste(collapse = ";")

wb <- wb_workbook() %>% 
  wb_add_worksheet() %>% 
  wb_add_data(x = species_year) %>% 
  wb_add_fill(dims = dims_to_fill, color = wb_color(hex = "FFC000")) %>% 
  wb_save("My Workbook.xlsx")

Created on 2024-04-18 with reprex v2.1.0

